# Monitor HTTPS traffic on an ios device or maybe remotely on the Internet

Tags: ipad, network, http

I want to monitor HTTPS network traffic on the Internet and not Intranet.  I would use a tool like Charles or Fiddler and setup a proxy but I could only host through Intranet. Plus, I have the issue of decrypting https traffic.

Ideally, I would like to monitor all http requests on the ios device, log to a file and then I can monitor the full data in that file.  Also, I am working Cordova/Xcode ObjectiveC code to create webviews, so the application I want to monitor is not a full browser like Safari.  I would be monitoring webrequests through that webview.

Is there a way to do this?  What applications in iTunes/Store are available to print out decrypted https requests.

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the IP-address where Charles is running as a proxy on your iPad you should be able to catch all traffic going to your iPad.

For HTTPS you need to install the Charles Certificate on your iPad and let Charles decrypt your HTTPS traffic en encrypt it again before sending it to your iPad (man-in-the-middle). In the Charles application it's called SSL-Proxying.

http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/

Comment: Yea, that won't work because the ip is on an intranet and won't be available.  Is charles or fiddler the only way to do this?  And that is more man in the middle proxying, is there no http monitoring on the device itself, maybe a hook into the network drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a more up to date guide in getting this working and with some further explanations. See if it would help

https://medium.com/@jamesmarino/monitoring-ios-https-network-traffic-a5d9fbe0edfe#.g2ud4pida

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.